# iPhone SDK 4 - How to enable TV out for your app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there any way to enable TV output for your app to present your app via a dock connector tv out cable?

Thanks for any help.

(App Store approval is not necessary)

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660473/using-uiscreen-to-drive-a-vga-display-doesnt-seem-to-show-the-uiwindow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output iPad content to external display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620646/output-ipad-content-to-external-display)

Comment: See also [Possible to mirror iPhone/iPad screen on a monitor without jailbreaking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289147/possible-to-mirror-iphone-ipad-screen-on-a-monitor-without-jailbreaking)

Comment: If you're doing this for presentation purposes: Just buy an iPhone4S or iPad2. Those devices mirror your screen, without the use of any "special" code.

Comment: Hey chris found any solution ??? I have solution fot this but what actually is your requirement let me know first